# T-SQL Script to get tempDB location that will return True or False

Tags: sql-server, dsc

I'm making an automation script to move tempDB files to another disk. I'm using DSC (with xSQLServerScript modules) to ensure consistent environment across multiple servers. In order not to touch servers that have tempDB in the right location already I need to reference a script that will return only True or False value. As I'm an SQL noob I would really appreciate if somebody would provide an example for such script.
If that makes any difference here is the T-SQL script I use to move tempDB files:

```
Alter database tempdb modify file (name = tempdev, filename = 'D:\Sqldata\tempdb.mdf', SIZE = 1000MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
Alter database tempdb modify file (name = templog, filename = 'D:\Sqldata\templog.ldf', SIZE = 100MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question here. Are you wanting to query the database to find the location of the files for tempdb? You can see the location of the tempdb files with this query. select filename from tempdb.sys.sysfiles

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. But I need the result of the query to return 'True' if tempDB is located on disk D and 'False' if it is located in the default location.

Comment: Well you could have one file on D and another on E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat unclear on what you want here but think you want to know if all files for tempdb are located on the D drive. Since I don't much care for strings representing true/false I am using the bit datatype here. The bit datatype will convert to 1 for any value that is not null and not 0.

```
select convert(bit, COUNT(*))
from tempdb.sys.sysfiles
where left(filename, 1) = 'D'
```

Comment: After reading documentation more thoroughly for the DSC module I use xSQLServerScript it turned out that I actually needed 0 or 1. Thanks, a lot!